# Angular CLI build --prod fails with tsconfig.json "noUnusedParameters" ser to true and Angular Material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2, tsconfig

I am starting to use the `"noUnusedParameters": true` and  `"noUnusedLocals": true` options of tsconfig.json

I find them very useful to keep code clean highlight since they make evident unused imports and variables.

The problem is that when I try to build a prod package with `ng build --prod` command I get a lot of errors of the type

```
ERROR in ng:///...../node_modules/@angular/material/form-field/typings/index.d.ts.MdFormField_Host.html (2,1): '$event' is declared but never used.
```

for Angular Material components, and similar errors for my personal components, e.g.

```
ERROR in ng:///.../src/app/components/my-comp/my-comp.component.html (5,9): '$event' is declared but never used.
```

Everything works fine if I switch off the tsconfig.json options, but I would like to know if there is a way of overcoming this problem.

I am using Angular 4.4.3 and Angular Material 2.0.0-beta.11

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is already merged PR on angular/material github:

https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/4946

Your code needs to be fixed by you of course :]

Also there is some discussion connected to this problem in angular/core:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/17131

One of suggestions there is to drop the `noUnusedParameters` option from `tsconfig.json` and use `no-unused` rule in `tslint.json` instead:

https://github.com/ajafff/tslint-consistent-codestyle/blob/master/docs/no-unused.md